# How do I configure Nginx to allow me to call a PHP script with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, json, nginx

Trying to save an object to a JSON file in javascript by converting the object to JSON (via JSON.stringify), and passing the stringified JSON to a PHP script using AJAX. However, this continually throws a 405 error. I suspect this has to do with the config file of my Nginx server, or it could be that I'm not hosting the PHP properly. I've seen the phrase 'static hosting' mentioned, which is unclear to me. Currently, the PHP script exists in the same directory as my HTML and javascript (the data in the object was collected via the HTML interface). I've tried adding headers in the nginx config with no success. General examples on how to enable CORS and hosting PHP with Nginx would be helpful.

Javascript :

```
$.post('save.php', {data : jsonData});
```

Nginx config currently has no headers added as this has not been successful in the past.

Comment: what does your console say in the network tab on the request beeing made?

Comment: 405 - method not allowed - at a guess, it could be that something in the client is triggering a CORS preflight, and your PHP code doesn't handle the CORS `OPTIONS` preflight request

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/854425/405-not-allowed-on-post-request

Comment: It shouldn't be CORS because the php is in the same directory as the HTML the JavaScript is calling from

Comment: And yes, it's 405 method not allowed. I suspect it has to do with my nginx configuration or how I'm hosting the php

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. The problem was with the PHP hosting. The default config file has a commented portion that forwards PHP to a server at 127.0.0.1:9000. I call this script with '127.0.0.1:9000/myScriptName.php'.

Now if only the PHP script itself would work...